# Merging filled row cells with ignoring empty cells in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merging-data

After some data preprocessing, I am stuck with merging the datasets. What I would like to do is to merge all dates under the same column as following in a row order according to same batch number. Normally it was stacked data, then I have unstacked according to process steps (40,42,50). Then my intention is to take the time difference of two columns as minutes.

DATASET:

```
         process     40-------------------42-----------------------50

index   batch   

64177   699042  NaT------------------2019-01-10 18:28:05-------NaT

171272  699042  NaT------------------NaT-------------------- 2019-01-10 18:28:20

120655  699042  2019-01-10 17:40:09--NaT----------------------NaT

120656  699043  2019-01-10 17:40:09--NaT----------------------NaT

67362   699043  NaT------------------2019-01-10 20:43:25-------NaT

168373  699043  NaT------------------NaT-----------------------2019-01-10 20:43:33
```

WHAT I WANT IS:

```
         process     40-------------------42-----------------------50
batch   

699042  2019-01-10 17:40:09-----2019-01-10 18:28:05-------2019-01-10 18:28:20

699043  2019-01-10 17:40:09----2019-01-10 20:43:25-------2019-01-10 20:43:33
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `groupby` with `first`

```
urdf=df.groupby(level=1).first()
```

Comment: It absolutely solved my problem. I have not considered the usage of "level" and "first" term in groupby.  I learnt new thing. I will exercise on that.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @OmerElmasri yw:-) happy holiday

Comment: happy holiday to you :)